# Como puedo hacer que se le atribuya un valor diferente cada vez que mi función cree una tabla

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Estoy intentando crear una función que cada vez que sea llamada cree una tabla en mi base de datos.
He conseguido que cree una pero con el mismo nombre, quiero ver a ver si se le puede atribuir un nombre diferente cada vez que se cree una tabla. Sería tipo algoritmo, por ejemplo tabla (como nombre común) y después un número solo por ejemplo (1232). Que daría la tabla1232, pero en la siguiente tabla que en vez de tabla1232 sea tabla1233. Como un algoritmo.
Estoy trabajando en `php`.
La tabla se manda a a crear a partir de una función llamada por un botón:

```html
function test()

{
$dbhost = "****";      
$dbuser = "*****";        
$dbpass = "******";          
$dbname = "tablebase";    


$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   } 

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE `tablebase`.`table1` ( `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `message` TEXT NOT NULL , `Name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB ";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table created successfully";
  } else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
  }
}

if(array_key_exists('test',$_POST)){
   test();
}
```

Aquí pueden ver como tabla1 se crea, pero que pasaría si se llamara a la función otra vez, ya no tendría que llamarse tabla1, sino tabla2(o cualquier número al azar). Este es el problema que tengo.

Comment: Puedes hacerlo de varias formas, se me ocurren dos, una es un poco de curro que sería leer las tablas que hay con el formato tablaNUMERO y a la parte NUMERO, incrementar en uno, la segunda opción la veo más lógica y es usar microtime para generar un número pseudoaleatorio, como usas microtime no se repite, la ayuda la tienes en https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.microtime.php o puedes usar la función uniqid que hace precisamente eso: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.uniqid.php

Comment: tambien puedes hacerte una consulta al [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-infoschema-excerpt/8.0/en/information-schema.html#:~:text=INFORMATION_SCHEMA%20provides%20access%20to%20database,data%20dictionary%20and%20system%20catalog.) del mysql para contar el numero de tablas con este nombre para esa base espesifica

Comment: de esa manera te la traes con una consulta le sumas 1 y se lo concatenas al `CREATE TABLE tabla` para que cree tablas en secuencia

Comment: ¿Por qué motivo habría que crear tablas de forma dinámica? ¿Hay algo que lo justifique realmente?

Comment: Buena pregunta A. Cedano, igual hay un mal planteamiento de fondo.

Comment: No es una buena idea crear una table diferente cada vez. Es mucho más simple usar una sola tabla con clave compuesta.

Comment: @A.Cedano Señor Cedano, he creado un chat que utiliza que guarda los mensajes en una tabla en phpmyadmin. Esto para un chat común funciona perfecto. Pero quiero que los usuarios tengan chats entre ellos, a eso va lo de las tablas. Estas tablas viven en la misma base de datos. Crear tablas de forma dinámica sería útil cuando el usuario quiere crear un chat entre el otro usuario especifico.

Comment: @track3r Gracias estoy leyendo los artículos que has mostrado. Pero me gustaría preguntarle si es una buena práctica el método que voy a usar?

Comment: @TheImpaler Entiendo lo que dice, puede que sea una sobrecarga para la base tener tantas tablas en ella, pero no entiendo cuando se refiere a una tabla con clave compuesta, he estado mirando pero no consigo entenderlo.

Comment: Según lo que le comentas a A. Cedano, no necesitas crear una tabla por chat, solo tienes que tener en la tabla chat un id a la tabla de chats, por ejemplo, una tabla que se llame salas con un id, un nombre, el propietario, etc... luego una tabla chat con el id, el id del chat, el id del user y su mensaje. De esta forma no tienes que crear tablas y simplificas mucho a la hora de buscar contenido y demás.

Comment: Entonces queda claro que no se justifica la creación de tablas dinámicas. Puedes tener una tabla para los chats de todos los usuarios, por el ID del usuario sabrás a qué usuario corresponde cada chat. Ten en cuenta que una tabla es algo así como una entidad que sirve para representar una realidad genérica de tu aplicación: la realidad chat, la realidad persona, la realidad ciudad, la realidad sala, etc. Querer crear una tabla por cada ente particular sería absurdo, imagina que por cada persona creas una tabla, o por cada ciudad, o por cada chat... No tiene sentido en un modelo relacional.